# Como re dimensionar una imagen en laravel?

Tags: php, html5, laravel, sublimetext3, crud

Esta es la función que tengo que guarda la imagen todo funciona bien, pero quiero saber como puedo hacer para re dimensionar las imágenes y rellenar las imagenes para no distorsionar, como agregar un margen, ya sea de forma vertical u horizontal de acuerdo a como sea necesario para re dimensionar la imagen sin distorsionarla.

```
public function store(CreateproductoRequest $request)
    {
            $input = $request->all();



        if($request->file('imagen_producto'))
    {       $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',$request->file('imagen_producto'));
            $input['imagen_producto'] = $path;
    }

                $producto = $this->productoRepository->create($input);
                Flash::success('Producto saved successfully.');
                return redirect(route('producto.index'));
    }
```

Instale Intervention Image

El codigo me quedo asi:

```
    image = $request->file('imagen_producto');
    $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(300,300);


    $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',$image_resize->file('imagen_producto'));

$input['imagen_producto'] = $path;
```

Ahora me salta este error

```
NotSupportedException in AbstractDriver.php line 117:
Command (File) is not available for driver (Gd).
```

Comment: Puedes usar la librería Intervention Image que permite cambiar la resolución de las imágenes: http://image.intervention.io/

Answer (score 0):

hay muchas herramientas para la manipulación de imagenes, recientemente use esta libreria es muy intuitiva y facil de usar.

[Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) y lo que búscas esta [aquí](http://image.intervention.io/api/resize)

Espero sea de tu utilidad.

Saludos!

Comment: He usando Intervention Image pero me tira este error: Command (File) is not available for driver (Gd). A que se debe ? este es el código que implemente. 
`$image = $request->file('imagen_producto');
                $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(300,300);`

Comment: Debes habilitar esta librería en tu `php.ini` solo quitale el `';'` a `extension=php_gd2.dll`. Posteriormente reinicia tu servidor apache y listo.

Comment: ya intente lo que me dijiste el problema persiste, no se que puedo hacer, creo que el error al momento de subir el archivo, ahi utilizo file para invocar la imagen, ya edite la pregunta para que puedas ver y me puedas ayudar. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

```html
        public function subir_foto(Request $request){

            //Se declara el tipo de guardado
            Storage::disk('local');

            //capturar el nombre del archivo
            $nombre = time().$request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();

            //guardar la imagen en Storage
            $path = Storage::putFileAs(
                'img/', $request->file('file'), time().$nombre
            );
            
            //Ubicación de la imagen
            $real_path = public_path('/storage'.'/'.$path);

            //Cambiar de tamaño segun el aspecto
            Image::make($real_path)
                ->resize(900, null, function ($constraint){
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })
                ->save($real_path,72);

            //Retornar URL
            return $real_path;
        }
```

Fuente: https://codigosdeabner.blogspot.com/2021/09/cambiar-tamano-redimensionar-imagen.html